# PDO fetch loop never ends

Tags: php, pdo

I have a loop that never ends and its only pulling one record from the database.

I have a class that returns a list then I call that class function on a website where the while loop never stops echoing the data.

```
class exampleclass
{
public function get_list()
{
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT .. blah);
$query->bindParam("blah");
$query->execute();
return $query->fetch(PDO::FetchObj);
}
```

on the web page i have:

```
<?php
testobj = new exampleclass();
while ($obj = $testobj->get_list())
{
echo $obj->db_field;
}
?>
```

It pulls the one record from the database but it doesn't stop looping, it should just loop once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, quit that idea of creating objects out of DB rows. They look fancy yet totally useless.
Then learn how to return **whole result** and how to properly iterate over it:

```
public function get_list()
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT .. blah");
    $query->execute(array("blah"));
    return $query->fetchAll();
}

testobj = new exampleclass();
foreach ($testobj->get_list() as $row)
{
    echo $row['db_field'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Worked better than what I had.